# Quiero trabajar con este tipo de campo y que me falta para que pueda funcionar para un JSON

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Mi archivo de conexion esta asi:

conect.php

```
<?php
// Connect PHP PDO
$connect = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=comidas';
try {
    $db = new PDO($connect,'root','');
    $db->setattribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
            echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

mi archivo de consulta esta asi, separa raciones en una facultad.

ingreso.php

```
<?php
include ('conect.php'); 
if (isset($_GET['login']) AND isset($_GET['login'])) {
    $login = $_GET['login'];    
    $password = $_GET['password'];
}else{
    $login="";
    $password="";
}
$queryselectusuario = 'SELECT * FROM cuentas WHERE cuenta = :cuenta AND contraseña = :contraseña';
$queryusuario = $db-> prepare($queryselectusuario); 
$queryusuario -> bindValue(':cuenta', $login , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$queryusuario -> bindValue(':contraseña', $password , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$queryusuario -> execute(); 
$i=0;   
while ($resusuario = $queryusuario -> fetch (PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { 
    $i++;
    $Usuarios[] = array ('id'=>$resusuario-> id,'faculdad'=>$resusuario-> apodo, 'correo'=> $resusuario->correo, 'respuesta'=>$resusuario->comida);
}
if($i==0){
    $Usuarios[] = array ('id'=>'','facultad'=>'','correo'=> '', 'comida'=>'');
}
$json_string = json_encode($Usuarios);
$json_string = '{"length":'.$i.',"result":'.$json_string.'}';
echo $json_string;
?>
```

estube buscando algo de referncia pero no sabria como emplearlo se los dejo

```
#Charset
        $SQL ="
            SET character_set_results = 'utf8',
            character_set_client = 'utf8', 
            character_set_connection = 'utf8',
            character_set_database = 'utf8', 
            character_set_server = 'utf8'
        ";
        $db->execute($SQL);
        $db->setCharset('utf8');
        $db->setFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: muestra tu resultado y el resultado q deseas obtener.

Comment: solo quiero que pueda leer el campo **contraseña = :contraseña** ya que esta de esta manera dispuesta por seguridad, lo del contenido es lo de menos, es el tipo de campo como se a definido **Character set : latin1** y **Collation : latin1_swedish_ci**

Comment: Solo has una lectura de campo con el diseño en su composicion **contraseña** y yo uso el metodo de acceso PHP PDO.

Comment: Ok pero cual es el problema: la query no encuentra al usuario o el json que se imprime no es interpretado como un json válido?

Comment: el problema no es de JSON eso lo manejo muy bien, el problema es la base de datos que tiene un campo con la letra **"ñ"** asi lo quieren tener como seguridad y yo quiero hacer conexion y que no me vote error. solo accesar al el.

Comment: Bueno ya encontre la solucion, buscando, **include('engine/adodb/adodb.inc.php');**  en **connect.php**.  con eso me funciono a la perfección, es interesante con campos de una tabla con **"ñ"** que era mi caso... 
para una consulta **$user = $db->getAll("SELECT cuenta , contraseña FROM cuentas WHERE cuenta='".$login."' AND contraseña='".$password."'");** y una ejecucion **$user = $db->execute("UPDATE cuentas SET contrraseña ='".$newpassword."' WHERE cuenta='".$login."'");** ya lo demas de JSON sale rapido.....